# How to set and display parameters in birt report using java class (struts 2)?

Tags: struts2, birt

How do i set parameters in Birt report using Struts2 ? and then how can i display them back on report ? explain in terms of

```
test = params["test"].value;
```

in open method

`row["test"]=test;` in fetch method

i am using latest birt 4.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a reason for it to be different than standard Apache

Link to report with

```
http://server:port/ContextName/run?__report=reportName.rptdesign&ParaName=(Value)
```